# How to solve $\arcsin(\sin(x))=\pi/9$

Tags: real-analysis

Please I have these equations, I solve it and I want to know if it is true

1) $\arcsin(\sin(x))=\pi/9 $

I found $\begin{cases} x=\pi/9+2k\pi,\,k\in \mathbb{Z}\\ x=\frac{8\pi}{9}+2k'\pi,\,  k'\in\mathbb{Z}\end{cases}$

I do $\sin(\arcsin(\sin(x))=\sin(\pi/9)$ then $\sin(x)=\sin (\pi/9)$ and I apply the definition

is it true ?

Comment: Why $\arccos$ ??

Comment: That is correct. It is simpler to write it in terms of congruences $\bmod 2\pi$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it is a typo I edited

Comment: @Bernard i muste reduce the solution on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ ?

Comment: As it is formulated, no – $x$ lives where it wants. I just made the remark that it is more expressive (in my opinion) and shorter to write  $x\equiv \frac\pi 9,\frac{8\pi} 9\mod 2\pi$.

Comment: @Bernard please why $arcsin(sin(x))\neq x$?

Comment: Because $\arcsin(\sin x)$, by definition, is the arc which has the same sine as $x$ but is comprised in the interval $\bigl[-\frac\pi 2,\frac\pi2\bigr]$. So it is $x$ if the latter is in this interval, and is only congruent to $x$ if it is not.

Comment: $\arcsin(\sin x)$ is a triangle wave, a continuous, periodic and piecewise linear function.

Answer (score 1):

As the function $\arcsin$ is invertible you can indeed apply its inverse and

$$\arcsin(\sin x)=\frac\pi9\implies \text{id}(\sin x)=\sin\frac\pi9.$$

Then you are right,

$$x=\frac\pi9+2k\pi\lor x=\pi-\frac\pi9+2k\pi.$$

Comment: Can you find the exact value of k?

Comment: @lindaOiladali: no of course.

Comment: whene we have sin(x)=sin(y) with $x\in ]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$ we say $x=y , y\in ]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$ or $x=\pi-y$